# javascript testing length

Tags: javascript

If I have an object MyObject that contains an array of objects ListOfOtherObjects and I write this:

```
   if (MyObject.ListOfOtherObjects.length !== 0) {...}
```

to test and see if the array contains OtherObjects, is it the same as writing this:

```
   if (MyObject.ListOfOtherObjects) {...}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'd do `if ( arr.length > 0 ) { ...`. Just `if ( arr.length ) { ...` would also do, but is not as clear...

Comment: @frenchie: What happened when you tested it for yourself? In doing this testing, did you notice that with `if (MyObject.ListOfOtherObjects) {`, empty Arrays behave identically to non-empty Arrays?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope, you need to check the `length` property. An `Array` is always *truthy*, like any other `Object`.

You can, however, omit the explicit check of `!== 0`.

```
if (MyObject.ListOfOtherObjects.length) {...}
```

This condition will be `true` if the `Array` has at least one element.

Comment: Assuming not null or undefined.

Comment: @CalgaryCoder: I don't quite get what you mean.

Comment: Your origional answer said MyObject.ListOfOtherObjects as an array will always be true. The answer was expanded, so ignore.

Comment: @CalgaryCoder: That's correct. Variable's values have types, variables themselves don't.